# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Table

Tags: python, python-camelot

I'm trying to extract some tables in a big pdf with camelot.
This is working but now I want to extract every single table from the TableList renaming the tables eachtime.
Here is an extract from my code :

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf("file.pdf", pages = "1")

table = ""
for i in tables:
   globals()['table'+str(i)] = tables[i]
```

And I have this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Table

In this case I have 2 tables in the first page in the final issue I have hundreds pages and tens of tables.

Comment: Unrelated advice: don't manipulate global namespace like that, it'd be much simpler to put all the tables in a dictionary.

Comment: Please try to explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When I read the pdf, camelot extract many tables and I want only some of them. So I want cut the TableList in tables and remove the usuless ones. I hope I m clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf("file.pdf", pages = "1")

table = ""
for i in tables:
   globals()['table'+str(i)] =i
```

Try this one. Because your `i` now is an table object.

incase you want indexing.

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf("file.pdf", pages = "1")

table = ""
for i in range(len(tables)):
   globals()['table'+str(i)] =tables[i]
```